# Can I read and change the values of android xml file like colors or string?

Tags: android, styles

I want to set the different colors for different events like as theme means I am applying the blue color for some button for the whole application but after any event I want to set it to red color instead of blue so I was simply trying to change the value of the colors attribute means changing the hexadecimal value blue to hexadecimal value of red. But that's not working. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the colorcode (hexadecimal value) for both red and blue in your color xml and change at runtime by using if else conditions.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the late reply,but I want to change the color of complete application and user will select the colors and there are near about 8 to 10 colors.

Answer (score 0):

```
I think you need to change the button color value form color.xml file. I hope this will help you ! 
You need the define the color value in color.xml file in Values directory :

  <item name="blue" type="color">#00385a</item>
  <item name="red" type="color">#a0a8ad</item>

in your java file you need to do like as this:  

    if(color=="blue"){
        btnAdd2Cart.setBackgroundColor(R.color.blue);
    }else if(color=="red"){
        btnAdd2Cart.setBackgroundColor(R.color.red);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read this at runtime but can't change it because of the permission on Android.

So you can't let your `color.xml` be your app's settings file.

Generally, the settings files should be read at runtime using `SharedPreferences` or other ways instead of using files in res directory.